# Creating a nested list referencing specific ranges

Tags: python, algorithm, list, range

I was challenged by a friend to make a simple program that asks a user to input a maximum value, and then a sample size (n). It then just uses randint to create a histogram in shell using ascii characters.

I can establish the class width and boundaries very easily. Where I'm having trouble is in understanding and implementing some sort of algorithm that will append all numbers that fall within a specific class to the histogram list to be printed. For example, if I have:

```
sample = [5, 1, 3, 9, 7, 13, 12, 5]
class_boundaries = [(1, 4), (4, 7), (7, 10), (10, 14)]
histogram = []
```

I just need to make a function that appends the sample values in the position that they would belong to in reference to the class boundaries. So for example, histogram[0] should return [1, 3]. I've been doing my best to try different solutions and understand how for-loop algorithms or list comprehensions function, but a practical explanation to my problem would be really helpful in my quest to better understand how to program. Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: For the finished program, I'm using len(histogram[i]) to print out a histogram. For this example though, printing out the different lists inside the histogram list is ideal to understanding the problem. So: print histogram[0] in should return [1, 3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sample = [5, 1, 3, 9, 7, 13, 12, 5]
class_boundaries = [(1, 4), (4, 7), (7, 10), (10, 14)]
classified = [[X for X in sample if LO <= X <= HI] for LO,HI in class_boundaries]
counts = [sum(LO <= X <= HI for X in sample) for LO,HI in class_boundaries]
```

Result: classified = [[1, 3], [5, 7, 5], [9, 7], [13, 12]], counts = [2, 3, 2, 2]

The computation of the counts doesn't need classified, so if thats all you need, skip the classified step.

Comment: `sum(LO <= X <= HI for X in sample)` is the same as you if else

Comment: Thanks so much! It's all pretty self-explanatory, but I was still having trouble writing and understanding the list comprehension on my own.